# How to calculate $\frac{100!}{(50!)^2 2^{100}}$ solely using mental arithmetic?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Question: When $100$ coins are tossed, what is the probability that exactly $50$ are heads?

I mange to solve the question with answer 
$$\binom{100}{50} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100} = \frac{100!}{(50!)^2 2^{100}}.$$

But if I want to approximate the quantity above solely using mental arithmetic, how would one approach it?

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: This link shows you how to do it using Stirling's Formula: https://books.google.com/books?id=8EDCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22When+100+coins+are+tossed,+what+is+the+probability+that+exactly+50+are+heads?%22&source=bl&ots=GHhg4H3OOC&sig=ACfU3U3wBQOudvsSkuDUPo29kFZneOJe1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDxsTFnI7lAhVwUN8KHbBLDAsQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22When%20100%20coins%20are%20tossed%2C%20what%20is%20the%20probability%20that%20exactly%2050%20are%20heads%3F%22&f=false

Comment: Actually, to be more precise, I would like to approximate the quantity just using mental arithmetic. I doubt that Stirling's formula is good for mental arithmetic? Edited my post.

Comment: I feel like Stirling's approximation could work decently for mental arithmetic, especially given how much cancellation results. (Though I might be biased since I had written up a partial answer using it before seeing these comments.) Of course the end result isn't so nice for mental arithmetic unless it's enough for you to go "eh good enough I'll dump it into my calculator now". [cont]

Comment: For what it's worth, using the approximation, I got

$$\frac{100!}{(50!)^2 \cdot 2^{100}} \approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{10 \sqrt{\pi}}$$

Wolfram gives this to be $\approx 0.079788$, where the exact value is $\approx 0.079589$. The percentage error is about $0.250309\%$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stirling is a reasonable approach here.  We have 
$$\frac{100!}{(50!)^2 2^{100}}\approx \frac {100^{100}e^{50}e^{50}\sqrt{2\pi 100}}{50^{50}50^{50}e^{100}2^{100}(2\pi 50)}=\frac 1{\sqrt{50\pi}}\approx \frac 1{7\cdot 1.8}=\frac 1{12.6}$$
Where I took $\sqrt{50} \approx 7$ and $\sqrt \pi \approx 1.8$ because $\sqrt 3 \approx 1.732$ and $\pi$ is a little greater than $3$

I did this without checking with [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2850%21%5E2%292%5E100%2F100%21), which shows it is about $\frac 1{12.56}$

Comment: Might be easier to see that $50 \pi \approx 157$, and it's pretty straightforward to see that the square root of that is a bit more than halfway from $12$ to $13$.

Comment: @BrianTung:  good point.  I did what came to mind in the spirit of mental computation.

Comment: Understood!  I tend to prefer being nearly exact as long as possible, and use approximations only toward the end.  But I suspect it really doesn't matter for the OP's concerns.

Comment: $7\times 1.8 = 12.6$. At the end, you probably meant $1/12.6$.

Comment: @Malkoun:  that is one of the risks of mental calculation.  I wondered why it came out so far off.  Thanks.

Comment: @Malkoun: Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

Completely aside from the mental math estimation, you may see that the standard deviation of the number of heads is $\sqrt{100(0.5)(0.5)} = 5$, which means that the probability of being between $45$ and $55$ is approximately $68/10 = 6.8$ percent, which we can bump up based on the fact that the peak is higher than the average (duh).  This gives us a decent ballpark estimate.

---

This seems as good an opportunity as any to plug my version of the [empirical rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule):

- The probability of being outside one standard deviation is approximately one in $\pi$.
- The probability of being outside two standard deviations is approximately one in $7\pi$.
- The probability of being outside three standard deviations is approximately one in $16e^\pi$.

Comment: +1 Your version of the empirical rule is amazing, but where did you get those approximations from? Are they from approximating the integrals?

Comment: Probability of 68/10? There must be a typo there, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Haha, sorry that was confusing; the "percent" applies to both the $68/10$ and the $6.8$. ;-)

Comment: @TobyMak: I wish.  No, these are just lucky coincidences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

For large factorials you can use stirling's formula
$$n! \approx (\sqrt{2\pi}) n^{n+0.5}e^{-n}$$

But if you want to be more accurate you can use Ramanujan's factorial formula

$$n! \approx \sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \left(8n^3+4n^2+n+\frac{1}{30}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Comment: I suspect Ramanujan's formula only counts as mental math for Ramanujan and von Neumann! :-P

Comment: I suppose that include Shakuntala devi too :P

Comment: Let's say "yes"! :-)